# Intermittent connection reset errors on multiple sites using chrome, mingw curl and nodejs on Windows, but not in PowerShell or Linux VM

Tags: node.js, curl, github

This started happening a month or two ago. I have a node script which fetches from:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glowbuzzer/gbr/master/package.json
```

This has started failing about one in three times, but not with all methods (all running on the same machine).

❌ curl under Git for Windows

❌ nodejs script in Windows

❌ curl in Ubuntu under WSL

❌ nodejs in Ubuntu under WSL

✅ Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell

✅ curl in guest Linux VM

✅ nodejs script in guest Linux VM

I've tried on home and work network with the same behaviour.

I suspect an SSL handshake issue. If Invoke-WebRequest didn't work in PowerShell, I would assume this was a corrupt Windows keystore or similar. Note that curl in Git for Windows is compiled using `schannel` (see log output).

Have done a fair amount of googling but cannot find anyone with quite the same problem. I should stress that this is *intermittent* - does not error on every request.

Any help much appreciated. Full logs follow.

### Under Git for Windows

```
$ curl --version
curl 8.1.2 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/8.1.2 Schannel zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.5 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.3) libssh2/1.11.0
Release-Date: 2023-05-30
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HSTS HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM PSL SPNEGO SSL SSPI threadsafe UnixSockets zstd

$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glowbuzzer/gbr/master/package.json
curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection was reset

$ cat <<EOF > fetch.mjs
import https from "https";

console.log("making request")
const res=https.request("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glowbuzzer/gbr/master/package.json", res => {
    console.log("statusCode", res.statusCode);

    res.on("data", d => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
    res.on("error", e => {
        console.error(e);
    });
    res.on("end", () => {
        console.log("No more data in response.");
    });
});

res.end()
EOF

$ node fetch.mjs
making request
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

### Under WSL (Ubuntu)

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glowbuzzer/gbr/master/package.json
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443

# same script as above in fetch.mjs

$ node fetch.mjs
making request
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:720:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1605:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: null,
  host: 'raw.githubusercontent.com',
  port: 443,
  localAddress: undefined
}
```

### PowerShell

```
> Invoke-WebRequest https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glowbuzzer/gbr/master/package.json


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
```

Comment: This seems to have become worse since updating to Windows 23H2. It now happens regularly in Chrome and using curl on multiple websites. Any help on diagnosis appreciated. Don't think it can be low-level network drivers because it works fine in HyperV which is using the underlying network stack. Something higher up in Windows.

Comment: Any difference between Windows PowerShell (5.1) and PowerShell [Core 7.x]?

Comment: Is a proxy or a layer-7 firewall with SSL inspection involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the Killer Network Service seems to have fixed it for me. Disabling ipv6 on the network adapter also seemed to fix it, but I prefer to disable Killer Network Service.

Based on answers here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/random-connection-reset-error/6ca8afce-f190-4b3d-955f-2dcdda6a7e79?page=3